# JavaScript: Is it possible to disable a click event only on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to disable a JavaScript click event only on mobile but keep it on desktop?

Comment: What is mobile? What is desktop? Where exactly do you draw the line?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: I just need to disable the click event for a carousel on mobile devices. With mobile device  I mean iPhone, Samsung phone etc.

Comment: What about tablets? Convertibles? Touch screens on desktops?

Comment: You could use `ResizeObserver` API to achieve the desired result by adding the resize observer on the `body` element. Following demo removes click listener from the button document's `body` width is smaller than or equal to `400px`. This not only works when the page first loads but also when window is manually resized.[Demo](https://jsbin.com/doyemabiri/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: @user1941537 But, *why* are you trying to disable click events?  It isn't clear at all what you're trying to do and why.  If you'd explain what the problem is, we can probably suggest a better way to deal with it.  I'm guessing you actually want to handle touch events instead, but instead you're fixated on mobile and won't tell us what exactly it is you want to accomplish.  Therefore, it's unlikely you'll get useful help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the start of your function for the click event

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var Android = userAgent.indexOf("android") > -1; 
if (Android)
    return;
```

iphone and ipad can also be checked

Comment: Thanks. Will this support only Android phones?

Comment: @user1941537 you can check for iphone as well. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to check. It's just a way I used recently which was for a specific use case. What is your end goal for this?